# How to add minutes in a column?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a call activity .csv file downloaded from my vonage account and I wanted to add up all the minutes in a column. I know how to add numbers but not sure how can I do it for minutes.

```
Date/Time       Type        Number      Length
7/3/2014 10:25  Extension   ########### 0:25
7/3/2014 10:18  Extension   ########### 6:59
7/3/2014 10:10  Extension   ########### 0:20
7/3/2014 9:51   Extension   ########### 1:18
7/3/2014 9:39   Extension   ########### 4:35
7/3/2014 9:25   Extension   ########### 0:55
7/3/2014 9:22   Extension   ########### 1:39
7/3/2014 9:14   Extension   ########### 2:46
7/3/2014 9:07   Extension   ########### 1:17
7/3/2014 9:01   Extension   ########### 2:28
7/3/2014 9:01   Extension   ########### 0:21
7/2/2014 12:55  Incoming    ########### 3:23
7/2/2014 9:26   Outgoing    ########### 14:26
7/2/2014 9:13   Outgoing    ########### 9:14
7/1/2014 22:48  Outgoing    ########### 14:29
7/1/2014 22:46  Extension   ########### 18:25
7/1/2014 20:14  Incoming    ########### 3:51
7/1/2014 10:09  Outgoing    ########### 1:48
6/30/2014 23:58 Outgoing    ########### 31:10:00
```

The last row is not in hours (in minutes)but excel is auto converting and adding :00 (for 31:10:00) at the end.

How to add the last column which is minutes to calculate total no. of minutes used in that .csv file ?

Thank you

Comment: Please take the time to format your question so it is clear for others to read; it'll probably result in a clearer question so more people will be able to help

Comment: Thank you @DaveRook. I was actually trying to format and you did it in the mean time.. Excellent !! Did you add that table as code ?

Comment: No, if you edit your post, you'll see you can make the text bold, italic etc. There is also an option to make text a quote or a code block (I chose code block).

Comment: Is the problem that, despite you knowing that 31:10:00 is minutes, seconds milliseconds, Excel thinks it is hours, minutes, seconds?

Comment: I think so. My question is what if Excel treats this as hours while adding up. I'm going to see a bloated number.

Comment: I'm now lost (sorry). Your question is "what happens if Excel does treats a value in an unexpected way", instead of "how to fix it so Excel"? If it's CSV, why can't you just change the value? Or is this just a small example of a larger amount of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood right, you want to sum up the minutes but the format is inconsistent.

First thing is to format the column. Click on the column and choose format to Time

This will make them all hh:MM:ss

Simply use `SUM()`

This will then show your result as hh:MM:ss

Comment: I haven't tried the first answer but this worked for me !!

Answer (score 1):

For time excel as default expects hh:mm:ss so it automatically will assume that the times provided are in that format. so it assumes 0:25 is 0 hours 25 mins

Best way iv'e found for this is in another column select the amount of rows that match your data, right click the selected rows and format.

Then on the custom category enter mm:ss into the type, and then copy the data from your Length column into this new column and auto sum it.

But there is probably a much better way of doing this.

just for reference this was done in a copy of excel 2010.